# I want a function to run forever but i dont want it to repeat

Tags: python, python-requests, kivy

I have a requests stream and i want the stream to run forever but i don't want it to repeat. i want the function to only update when there is new information on the stream, if i try to run it in intervals it repeats and the old information keeps adding to the container and continue to repeat till i close the application.

Here is my code, i would appreciate any amends to how to make the container update only new information.

```
    def processnotifications(self, dt):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        session = requests.Session()
        self.notif_stream = session.get("*********************************************************************" + app.displayname + "/.json", stream= True)
        print(self.notif_stream.json())
        if self.notif_stream.json() == None:
            return
        else:
            notifications = self.notif_stream.json()
            for key, value in notifications.items():
                self.notif = session.get("***************************************************" + app.displayname + "/" + key + "/" + "notification" + "/.json", stream = True)
                self.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([self.notif.json()])
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, While True: And then your function, It will keep on running, till the user force close the application.

Comment: Yeah but it updates its container with old information. i only want new information to update the container

Comment: Does this web site have a way of notifying you that the data changed? If not, the best you can do is poll for the json and compare with your last attempt.

Comment: @tdelaney i'll try and do that

Comment: @tdelaney any idea how i can do that?

Comment: I will write up an example

Comment: @tdelaney thank you bro

Comment: Looking a little more closely, I don't know enough about this API to know the best way to implement a poll. I don't know if `app.displayname + "/.json"` is a static list of all possible notifications or only those that have changed. I also don't know enough about individual notifications to know how well simple compares will work. I'll take a guess and see!

Comment: BTW, do you want the method to report new notifications?

Comment: @tdelaney yeah only new notifications, "app.displayname + "/.json" is just the link of the notifications for that specific user. app.displayname changes depending on the logged in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not happy with this solution - I'm making a lot of assumptions about the data and decided to keep track of the items that change between calls to the method. This could still be time consuming and not very friendly to the web site if called too often. So, more as a strawman than an answer...

I assume some external entity calls this method periodically and is interested in which events have changed since the last call. Those are kept as a set of keys on the object that is updated with each call.

```
# todo: add to __init__
#     # previous notifications and a set of changed keys since
#     # the last call to processnotifications
#     self.notfications = {}
#     self.notification_changes = set()    

def processnotifications(self, dt):
    base_url = "***************************"
    app = App.get_running_app()
    session = requests.Session()

    # assume no notification changes
    self.notification_changes = set()

    # todo: do you need to keep the session? best to drop those references if not needed
    # todo: you read the full json so no need to stream

    # get current notifications, if any
    notif_stream = session.get(f"{app.displayname}/.json")
    notifications = notif_stream.json()
    print(notifications)
    if notifications == None:
        return False

    # assuming notifications change every time there are subnotifications we could
    # check here.
    if notifications = self.notifications:
        return False

    # remember current notifications        
    self.notifications = notifications
    data = self.notificationslist.adapter.data

    # get each subnotification and track which ones have changed
    changes = set()

    # note: value unused.... so no need to iterate .items()
    for key in notifications:
        notif = session.get(f"{base_url}{app.displayname}/{key}/notification/.json").json()
        if notif:
            for subkey, value in notif:
                # update self.notificationslist.adapter.datad iff we
                # got a notification with a different value
                if data.get(subkey, "") != value:
                    data[subkey] = value
                    changes.add(subkey)

    # record the changes we saw
    self.notification_changes = changes
    return bool(changes)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code, im having problems understanding it